# How do i create a foreign key in sql server with multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, key

i'm trying to create foreign key:

```
create table visit
      (Num_vst int primary key,
      date_vst date,
      num_agnt int,
      code_type int,
      Constraint fk_vst foreign key (num_agnt,code_type) 
        references agente,type_de_verification  (num_agnt,code_type);
```

where is the problem?

Comment: You seem to have a typo in the name of the related table: `agente,type_de_verification`. This should be a single table name. Maybe that comma right there should be a dot.

Comment: @TheImpaler there 2 tables! like numa_agnt is related to agente and code_type is related to type_de_verification! a foreign key related with 2 tables! am i wrong?

Comment: A foreign key can only reference one table, and it must be a complete key too.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing two separate relationships to two tables:

> num_agnt is related to agente and code_type is related to type_de_verification

In this case you can define both foreign keys as shown below:

```
create table visit (
  Num_vst int primary key,
  date_vst date,
  num_agnt int,
  code_type int,
  constraint fk1 foreign key (num_agnt) references agente (num_agnt),
  constraint fk2 foreign key (code_type)
    references type_de_verification (code_type)
);
```